# ONVIF GetDeviceInformation SOAP Message

Tags: xml, soap, httpwebrequest

Im trying to make a web request to an onvif compliant camera but i am having trouble with the response.

I followed the ONVIF application programmer's guide and i came up with this soap message to get the device information:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope 
    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:tt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema" 
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
    xmlns:tds="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl">
    <s:Header>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsse:Username>admin</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wssusername-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">
                WndlORLsIdMIyyvb99lzSgm0iGI=
            </wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">
                Rjc0QUUzNDI2MTMyMTI4OTJCQjI1QzM2RUEzMDUzNEUxMTlFNEQ2Mg==
            </wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2017-05-11T11:48:56.8823852ZZ</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <GetDeviceInformation xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl" />
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And the response from the device is:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope (...)>
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <SOAP-ENV:Code>
                <SOAP-ENV:Value>SOAP-ENV:Sender</SOAP-ENV:Value>
            <SOAP-ENV:Subcode>
                <SOAP-ENV:Value>ter:NotAuthorized</SOAP-ENV:Value>
            </SOAP-ENV:Subcode>
            </SOAP-ENV:Code>
            <SOAP-ENV:Reason>
                <SOAP-ENV:Text xml:lang="en">Sender not Authorized</SOAP-ENV:Text>
            </SOAP-ENV:Reason>
        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Im calculating the Created time by subtracting the offset diference between my computer and the device so that the message is sent with a datetime compatible with the device.

Am i missing something in my request? Considering that the username and password is correct, what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after some on and off research and trial and error i managed to resolve my issue. I used wireshark to check what the Onvif Device Manager application was sending to the camera and ended up with this message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <s:Header>
        <Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <UsernameToken>
                <Username>admin</Username>
                <Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">6KZX13jsvYLOE72Fb7Nc4tCFE60=</Password>
                <Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">Xd0vNthkfp/VCmVtoHr3QA==</Nonce>
                <Created xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2017-06-01T10:29:01.001Z</Created>
            </UsernameToken>
        </Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <GetDeviceInformation xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl" />
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

To calculate the nonce and password digest i also changed the methods i was using and ended up with this one:

```
public static void GetPasswordDigest(string ONVIFPassword, TimeSpan CameraTimeOffset, out string nonceb64_out, out string created_out, out string passwordDigest_out)
        {
            //Get nonce
            Random rnd = new Random();
            Byte[] nonce_b = new Byte[16];
            rnd.NextBytes(nonce_b);
            string nonce64 = Convert.ToBase64String(nonce_b);
            nonceb64_out = nonce64;

            //Get timestamp
            DateTime created = DateTime.UtcNow - CameraTimeOffset;
            string creationtime = created.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");
            Byte[] creationtime_b = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(creationtime);
            created_out = creationtime;

            //Convert the plain password to bytes
            Byte[] password_b = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ONVIFPassword);

            //Concatenate nonce_b + creationtime_b + password_b
            Byte[] concatenation_b = new byte[nonce_b.Length + creationtime_b.Length + password_b.Length];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(nonce_b, 0, concatenation_b, 0, nonce_b.Length);
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(creationtime_b, 0, concatenation_b, nonce_b.Length, creationtime_b.Length);
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(password_b, 0, concatenation_b, nonce_b.Length + creationtime_b.Length, password_b.Length);

            //Apply SHA1 on the concatenation
            SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
            Byte[] pdresult = sha.ComputeHash(concatenation_b);
            string passworddigest = Convert.ToBase64String(pdresult);
            passwordDigest_out = passworddigest;

        }
```

This method is heavily based on someone elses answer to a different question here in StackOverflow, unfortunately i forgot to save the link or the person's name.
I hope this helps people that are in the same roadblock i was.

Answer (score 1):

This is just for other people who land here facing a similar problem. In general, specially if you don't know which authentication schemes a camera uses, you should send a `GetCapabilities` command. It belongs to the PRE_AUTH service class, so does not need any authentication, as its companion `GetSystemDateAndTime`. The response contains a `Capabilities` tree. Go to  `Device` node. The `Security` child has a description of what a camera supports. These are captures from real cameras:

1. Some models of "V380", "YC365" and "EyePlus":

   ```
     <tt:TLS1.1>false</tt:TLS1.1>
     <tt:TLS1.2>false</tt:TLS1.2>
     <tt:OnboardKeyGeneration>false</tt:OnboardKeyGeneration>
     <tt:AccessPolicyConfig>false</tt:AccessPolicyConfig>
     <tt:X.509Token>false</tt:X.509Token>
     <tt:SAMLToken>false</tt:SAMLToken>
     <tt:KerberosToken>false</tt:KerberosToken>
     <tt:RELToken>false</tt:RELToken>
     <tt:Extension>
        <tt:TLS1.0>false</tt:TLS1.0>
     </tt:Extension>
   ```
2. Some models of "HikVision", "BoschCam":

   ```
     <tt:TLS1.1>true</tt:TLS1.1>
     <tt:TLS1.2>true</tt:TLS1.2>
     <tt:OnboardKeyGeneration>false</tt:OnboardKeyGeneration>
     <tt:AccessPolicyConfig>false</tt:AccessPolicyConfig>
     <tt:X.509Token>false</tt:X.509Token>
     <tt:SAMLToken>false</tt:SAMLToken>
     <tt:KerberosToken>false</tt:KerberosToken>
     <tt:RELToken>false</tt:RELToken>
     <tt:Extension>
        <tt:TLS1.0>true</tt:TLS1.0>
     </tt:Extension>
   ```

Cameras in section 2 do not accept requests with security information supplied in a header of the SOAP envelope. The models tested require TLS.

The [ONVIF core specification](http://www.onvif.org/specs/core/ONVIF-Core-Specification.pdf) is an important reference.